# How can configure the Magento 2 With Varnish Cache with HTTPS

Tags: amazon-ec2, https, magento2, varnish

Thank you for looking on this.

I have a Magento 2.1.8 website and it will run on the Amazon EC2 with this https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B007OUYR4Y Amazon AMI.

I have optimized everything on Magento 2 website but did not get the proper result on this.

I have tried to use the Varnish cache but it is not working with the HTTPS.

anyone have an idea, how can use the varnish with the HTTPS to optimize the website speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Varnish Cache does dot speak HTTPS natively. You'll need an SSL terminator such as [Hitch](https://hitch-tls.org/), [HAProxy](http://www.haproxy.org/), etc. deployed in front of Varnish, ideally using the PROXY protocol.

Comment: Apache or Nginx could be used as SSL/TLS terminators too, but since they are general purpose web servers, usually it's a better idea to use Hitch + PROXY protocol.

Comment: do you have any configuration steps that I can follow?

Comment: @SanjayVirja did you find a way to configure varnish on ec2? I'm trying to achieve the same for M1.

Comment: @DarkCowboy You can use the BitNami AWS AMI to configure all the things like apache, Varnish, etc..

Comment: @SanjayVirja thx for the hint. I hesitated to choose the BitNami or make a clean setup from scratch. Were you satisfied by the performance from BitNami AMI setup?

Comment: @DarkCowboy Yes, performance is better than setting up it from the scratch. previously I set up it from the scratch and once the tested it with the load testing tool, the server is crashed so switched to Bitnami AMI.

Comment: @SanjayVirja thank you for the hint. Can I ask you which load testing tool did you use? Siege?

Comment: @DarkCowboy We used this [Loading Testing Tool](https://loadimpact.com/)

Answer (score 0):

With my setups I use NGINX as a proxy to handle both http and https requests and then use Varnish as the backend so NGINX handles all the SSL certificates.

Here's an example of my NGINX ssl template:

```
server {
    listen  server-ip:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    ssl_certificate  /home/user/conf/web/ssl.example.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  /home/user/conf/web/ssl.example.com.key;

    location / {
      proxy_pass  http://varnish-ip:6081;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_set_header X-Nginx on;
      proxy_redirect     off;
    }

    location @fallback {
        proxy_pass  http://varnish-ip:6081;
    }


}
```